# In React how to sync 2 input state of search boxes when prop changes via redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have created SearchBox reusable component which receives 3 props

1. onSearchInputChanged : The function to be run when something is searched
2. Pleaceholder : strings like "search students"
3. searchString : initialize search box with this string

function passed to `onSearchInputChanged` calls an api via redux sagas and stores the data in redux. ie, it goes through 2 states `SEARCH_REQUEST`, `SEARCH_SUCCESS` where search string and search result are updated.

In want the same search box in home page and in a modal. When you have 2 instances of search boxes how do we sync search string in state of 2 instances and search string in redux ?

```
<SearchBox
  searchString={search_reducer.searchString}
  placeHolder={'Search students in home page'}
  onSearchInputChange={value => this.props.searchStudents({ searchString: value })}
/>

<SearchBox
  searchString={search_reducer.searchString}
  placeHolder={'Search students in modal'}
  onSearchInputChange={value => this.props.searchStudents({ searchString: value })}
/>
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';
import { Input, InputGroup } from 'reactstrap';
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';
import './SearchBox.css';

export class SearchBox extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    onSearchInputChange: PropTypes.func,
    placeHolder: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    searchString: PropTypes.string
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchParam: ''
    };
    this.changed = debounce(val => this.props.onSearchInputChange(val), 250);
  }

  onSearchChange = event => {
    if (event.target !== null) {
      const val = event.target.value;
      this.setState({ searchParam: val }, () => {
        this.changed(val);
      });
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.searchString !== this.state.searchParam) {
      this.setState({ searchParam: this.props.searchString });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="searchBoxContainer">
        <div className="searchInputGroup">
          <InputGroup className="inputGroup">
            <i className="searchIcon" />
            <Input
              value={this.state.searchParam}
              type="search"
              placeholder={this.props.placeHolder}
              className="searchInput"
              onChange={this.onSearchChange}
            />
          </InputGroup>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchBox;
```

Comment: If we use componentDidUpdate, then due to debounce and async way of updating redux on `SEARCH_SUCCESS `, we end up updating state in the searchbox with older searchstring.

Answer (score 0):

I'd directly access the redux store's state. you should already be receiving that state in your props so you shouldn't need to rely on setState() in your components. Lets say your slice of redux state for the search component is called 'search'. So in your redux connected component you'd have something like:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ search }) => {
```

if so, then you'd access this in your component as this.props.search.searchString